# XQuery - count + value of node

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, xquery

i have a small problem with getting count of something and value of parent node for it.
Actually xml schema looks like that:

`<car>
     <carID> 1 </car>
    <fixes>
     <fix>
      <fixID> 1 </fixID>
     </fix>
     <fix>
      <fixID> 2 </fixID>
     </fix>
    </fixes>
 </car>`

well more or less... what im trying to achieve is: by using XQuery (and thats important part) i need to return how many fixes each car has (i know that in example there is just one car). So i need in result something like  1  2 or something like that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:
   `<car>
     <carID> 1 </car>
     <departmentID> 1 </departmentID>
    <fixes>
     <fix>
      <fixID> 1 </fixID>
     </fix>
     <fix>
      <fixID> 2 </fixID>
     </fix>
    </fixes>
 </car>`

Now id like something a bit more troublesome ;/ I have XMLcolumn in sql server which hold sqldocument for car in a separate rows, so one row one . What im trying to do further on is to get carID for each department wich most amount of fixes. Any clue?;/

Comment: Wouldnt each `fix` have a `fixid`? (so two `fix`'s in your example?)

Comment: You are indeed correct, that is my mistake

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the closing `</carID>` tag,  you can apply the xpath `count` aggregate to return the `count` of fixes:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<car>
     <carID> 1 </carID>
    <fixes>
     <fix>
      <fixID> 1 </fixID>
      <fixID> 2 </fixID>
     </fix>
    </fixes>
 </car>';


SELECT
  Nodes.node.value('(carID)[1]', 'int') AS Car,
  Nodes.node.value('count(fixes/fix/fixID)', 'int') AS Fixes
FROM
  @xml.nodes('//car') AS Nodes(node);
```

[SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23126)

**Edit**
Update for OP's new Question.

You need to use `CROSS APPLY` to apply the xml scraping to a column for all rows in a table. Once you know how to project data out of an Xml Column, the rest becomes a simple matter of using successive Sql projections to move to the end result:

```
WITH cteCarFixes AS
(
    SELECT
      Nodes.node.value('(carID)[1]', 'int') AS CarId,
      Nodes.node.value('(departmentID)[1]', 'int') AS DepartmentId,
      Nodes.node.value('count(fixes/fix/fixID)', 'int') AS Fixes
    FROM
        CarFixes cf
        CROSS APPLY cf.SomeXml.nodes('//car') as Nodes(node)
),
cteRankedCarFixes AS
(
    SELECT CarId, DepartmentId, Fixes,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentId ORDER BY Fixes DESC) AS Ranking
    FROM
        cteCarFixes cf
)
SELECT DepartmentId, CarId, Fixes
    FROM
        cteRankedCarFixes
    WHERE
        Ranking = 1
```

[Updated SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdff8/1)

Comment: That indeed works thanks a lot. But now i have a bit different problem. I have XML instances in SQL Server. Please check Edit in main post if possible. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I've updated, above. Next time, please ask a new question (you will reach a wider audience and likely be a faster resolution).

Comment: This looks like SQL with some embedded Xpath expressions. Why tag it xquery?

Comment: @charlesross [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx) may help you

Comment: Yikes - MS 'XQuery' is a thing that is to the XQuery standard as the old Jscript was to Javascript. It presents a tagging problem here.